# Regex to replace only first space with dash

Tags: regex

I want to replace only the FIRST space in the line with a dash. This is somewhat complicated because the parser automatically applies /g to apply to the whole line.

Sample input:
A1 B2 Word word word

Desired Output:
A1-B2 Word word word

I can't do a simple /\s/-/ because the automatic /g will change all the spaces to dashes. I have tried a negative lookback /s(?<\s\w) and several other variations (word and boundary matching) but I end up matching either all of the spaces or I match the first or last character with the space so that I end up clipping out too much.

How do I replace only the first space with a globally-applied pattern?

Comment: What language? From the [tag:regex] tag description: "*Remember to include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.*"

Comment: Why does the parser apply a /g automagically?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
/^(\S*)\s/$1-/
```

The `^` specifies the beginning of the line, the `\S` matching all non whitespace characters. This will assume you don't have any leading whitespace, else your first character will be replaced with a -.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^` to indicate the beginning of a line:

```
/^.*?\s/$1-/
```